# Update using join Informix not working

Tags: sql, informix

```
UPDATE a
SET a.col = 1610
FROM tabl1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.appln_no = b.req_appln_no AND a.appln_no = 1
```

I keep getting a "A syntax error has occurred."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all databases support this syntax.  You can do this with an appropriate `where` clause:

```
UPDATE tabl1
    SET a.col = 1610
    WHERE tabl1.appln_no = 1 AND
          tabl1.appln_no IN (SELECT b.req_appln_no from table2 b);
```

Comment: THANKS! Worked perfectly! YAH DI BOSS!!